# How to change the mobile navigation menu screen width settings?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an issue with the navigation menu on: https://dialogueadvisorygroup.org/

I would like that the mobile navigation would kick in sooner (at around screen width 1300px) - just before the Careers menu tab moves out of place.

Here's what I've tried so far, unsuccessfully:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px){
.main_menu {
    display: none!important;
}
    .header_bottom, nav.mobile_menu {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
        display:block; 
}
}
```

Your help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance, 
Laura

Comment: Why don't you try a lesser value than 1300?

Comment: what happens when you use that?

Comment: You can have a look now and see. What happens is that the main menu disappears and the header-space is white - so far so good. But the navigation menu button doesn't appear..

Comment: you. need to change .mobile_menu_button and other's style on the 1300 max width...

Comment: Thanks Ziad. Do you know how I can do that..?